# Cypress -Cannot compare expected value

Tags: javascript, cypress

can someone pls advise what is the issue here?

```js
const amt1 = (+parseFloat((250.78+ 5005.58 + 20001.35) *
0.424)).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') 
const formattedamt1 = amt1.trim().replace(/\d{2}(?!$)/, '$& ')

cy.getBySel('amt1').should($test => {
    const test1 = $test.text().replace('€', " ").trim()
    expect(test1).to.include(formattedamt1)    
})
```

I am getting the error:

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '10 709,27' to include '10 709,27'

Aren't they the same?

Thank you

Comment: Can you copy/paste complete error text in formatted blcok?

Comment: Looks like the spacing between `10` and `709` is different. You can see the value change with an ASCII to hex conversion of each text.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you have a non-breaking-space inside the amount string on the the web page.

If so, you can remove it with a regex replacing `\s` with the space char

```js
cy.getBySel('amt1').should($el => {
  const text = $el.text()
    .replace('€', " ")
    .replace(/\s/g, ' ')                    // make &nbsp a normal space char
    .trim()
  expect(text).to.include(formattedamt1)    
})
```

or you could compare without any spaces

```js
const formattedamt1 = (+parseFloat((250.78+ 5005.58 + 20001.35) * 0.424))
  .toFixed(2)
  .replace('.', ',') 
  .trim()

cy.getBySel('amt1').should($el => {
  const text = $el.text()
    .replace('€', " ")
    .replace(/\s/g, '')                    // remove all whitespace
  expect(text).to.include(formattedamt1)    
})
```